# JQuery template not works with $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am populating a table with a Jquery Template. In this template, I need to use a json file through a ajax call to populate.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clientData;

    $.get("/webpro/webcad/lngetusuario", function(data, status){
        clientData = data;
        alert(clientData);
    });
    $("#clientTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo("tbody");

});

<script id="clientTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr><td> ${usuario} </td><td> ${nome} </td><td> ${setor} </td></tr>
     //{{tmpl($data) "#phoneTemplate"}}
</script>
```

The url '/webpro/webcad/lngetusuario' generate the json file.

This is the code. I don't understand this, because inside $.get statement the variable clientData are with the correct value json, but outside $.get statement(on document.ready) the variable clientData are empty. 
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a callback "feature".

The code isn't run in the order you think:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clientData;

    $.get("/webpro/webcad/lngetusuario", function(data, status){
        clientData = data; // This will be run when a response has been received from the server
        alert(clientData);
    });
   // This will run without waiting any reply from the server
    $("#clientTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo("tbody");

});
```

Here is want you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clientData;

    $.get("/webpro/webcad/lngetusuario", function(data, status){
        clientData = data;
        alert(clientData);
        $("#clientTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo("tbody");
    });

});
```

Comment: I try it before ask and aren't this the problem.

Comment: Maybe your problem is actually converting the server response to JSON, before using it for the template

Answer (score 0):

`$.get()` is asynchronous. So `$().tmpl()` executes before `$.get()` is done, resulting in `clientData` being empty. To fix this put `$().tmpl()` inside the `$.get()` callback. This will make sure that your template will only be created when the get request is complete. Like so

```
$.get("/webpro/webcad/lngetusuario", function(data, status){
    clientData = data;
    alert(clientData);
    $("#clientTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo("tbody");
});
```

Comment: I try it before ask and aren't this the problem.